# How to unpickle the files in python?

Tags: python, pickle

I have some pickle files which have trained machine learning models.
I want to unpickle them and want to see the code. I tried by writing these code lines.

```
import pickle
with open('cv.pickle','rb') as f:
    data_1 = pickle.load(f)
```

This code is giving the following error:

```
AttributeError                            Traceback (most recent call last)

<ipython-input-5-25ea81eeb394> in <module>()
      2 
      3 with open('cv.pickle','rb') as f:
----> 4     data_1 = pickle.load(f)

AttributeError: Can't get attribute 'dummy_fn' on <module '__main__'>
```

Comment: The short answer is that you cannot – your code refers to definitions which are no longer available. Do you know what was ``__main__.dummy_fn`` in the original code?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Pickle doesn't store the code only the variables, class names, import paths, etc. This is why it's easy to create problems with pickle if the supporting code changes.

The code that opens the pickle needs to be able to reach the classes/functions that are referenced in the pickle file. The problem here is that your pickle file references `dummy_fn` but that function does not exist in the main module you are unpickling in.

It looks like you're reading this in an ipython environment. Define the functions and classes in the same way that you did when you created the pickle file, then open the file.

To mitigate problems, you could define these classes/functions in a module and then just import the module when saving the file and when loading the file.